# Nebula Ospackage plugin incremental build issue

Tags: gradle, netflix-nebula-plugins

Using Nebula [RPM Plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/RPM-Plugin) I have some issues with incremental build support, for some of the ospackage extension properties.

See simple example below:

```
plugins {
  id "nebula.ospackage" version "9.1.1"
}

ospackage {
    packageDescription = "my sample package"
    user  "root"
    createDirectoryEntry true
    addParentDirs        true   
}
```

When changing `createDirectoryEntry` property value, Gradle properly detects the change and consideres the task as NOT up-to-date , as expected:

```
> Task :buildRpm
Caching disabled for task ':buildRpm' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':buildRpm' is not up-to-date because:
  Value of input property 'createDirectoryEntry' has changed for task ':buildRpm'
Created rpm java.io.RandomAccessFile@25ee06fa
:buildRpm (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.02 secs.
```

**BUT**
when changing `addParentDirs` propery value, the change is not detected, and task is considered as up-to-date!

```
> Task :buildRpm UP-TO-DATE
Caching disabled for task ':buildRpm' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping task ':buildRpm' as it is up-to-date.
:buildRpm (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.007 secs.
```

Both `addParentDirs` and `createDirectoryEntry` are simple Boolean properties with their getters correctly annoted with @Input, see https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/blob/main/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/gradle/plugins/packaging/SystemPackagingExtension.groovy#L71.

How can we explain the different behavior in up-to-date check for these two properties?

*Note*

Same behavior when using property assignment or not (e.g.:  `addParentDirs true` same effect as `addParentDirs = true` ) ; seems that there can be issues related to the syntaxe used, see https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/issues/82 and https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/issues/39

(Using Gradle v7.4, ospackage plugin v9.1.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause is that `addParentDirs` property defined in `ospackage` is simply ignore by nebula ospackage plugin, due to issue https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/issues/246.

So whatever value will be defined for this property in this extension, it won't affect the task configuration, I guess that's why it is ignored by the up-to-date check mecanism.